# footer not the same on every page

Tags: footer, gaps-in-visuals

I am relatively new to coding, html etc, and have only really written two websites before this. I am a graphic designer by profession and I am attempting a website provided by a client. I am still working on it but have come across a problem I just cant fix...

The footer appears to be different on every page, It is perfect on the home page, and seems to be ok on the about (apart from the gap underneath :/) but I cant sort it out on the testimonials or the contact.

Any help would be much appreciated
The site its currently on is: http://www.eplsdesign.com/grow/index.php

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are using `<font>` and `<b>` tags in the HTML. Nowadays, all styles (font, color, font-weight etc.) should always be specified via CSS. This makes the HTML much cleaner and easier to maintain.

Your pages look different because each page has a slightly different structure. On the Home page, the footer div is nested at the same level as your main content div. But on the Testimonials page, the footer is actually inside content. You need to be consistent with your page structure to achieve a consistent look. Getting rid of the `<font>` and `<b>` tags will help you do this.

I'd suggest you read up on basic HTML and CSS before continuing.

Comment: great but as i said before, I am still learning! As we speak I have a book entitled: basics of Html and CSS, and what better way to learn then playing with the code. Geez thanks for nothing.